# Laravel app routes not working after renaming

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-8

I recently finished off my laravel app, however, I decided to change the name of the project, I've renamed the project in config/app.php from laravel-app:

```
'name' => env('APP_NAME', 'M-Tech'),
```

and I also changed it in the .env file.

```
APP_NAME=M-Tech
```

However I also changed the folder names which the project is in from laravel-app to M-Tech-app and the parent folder to just M-Tech.

This has seemed to have a strange effect to the project, as the artisan route:list still shows all the routes, however they return 404 if you visit any page but the index page.

I'm not too sure whats gone wrong.

Comment: Did you also change your server configuration for Apache/nginx? Also try `php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: I didn't change anything in apache, i've done the cache:clear with no change

Comment: have you tried `composer dunp-autoload` ?

Comment: Yup I've trued composer dump-autoload

Comment: You probably should double-check your apache config, make sure that the DocumentRoot path matches what you changed the folder names to

Comment: Where do I find this DocumentRoot? I've never touched it so far? And the index page still works m-tech-app/public/ returns the index page?

Comment: It's usually in the Apache config files, often under /etc/apache2 or /etc/httpd

Comment: Try ```php artisan config:cache```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revert the changes you made to the `config/app.php`, and then rename the `APP_NAME` variable in the `.env` file as such:

```
APP_NAME=M-Tech
```

Also try using a name without a hyphen, something like this:

```
APP_NAME=MTech
```

Comment: Thanks, seems it doesn't like the hyphens. Now the storage is acting up haha

Comment: you can use quotes when using hyphens or other characters `APP_NAME='M-Tech'`